# MS Access hangs when comparing 2 link tables

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, compare, sybase

I have 2 link tables in a MS Access database. One of the link tables links to a table in a Sybase database and the other links to a SQL Server database.

The tables structures are same and has the same data too, barring a few rows.

I tried the 'Find unmatched rows' query wizard to compare the two tables and find the number of rows which are same (and different). But the problem is this makes the MS Access hang for huge tables (10 million+ rows).

Are there any settings that I can tweak so that Access does not hang? I am using ODBC connections to Sybase and SQL Server.

One more thing I noticed is when I right click on the SQL Server link table and click on open, it shows all the rows from the table. When I do the same for the Sybase one, it hangs and I have to close Access through Task Manager.

Some details:
Sybase version - 12.5.3
SQL Server version - 2008 R2
MS Access Version - 2003

Comment: Is it possible for you to do this in sql server : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/280102 ? It seems a bit of a stretch to involve Access.

Comment: Hi Remou, Thanks a lot for this suggestion. This seems perfect. Unfortunately, I dont have access to the server where SQL Server is installed. But if using Access does not work out at all, then I'll try to get the access and try the linked server method.

Comment: Yeah, +1 for doing this using linked servers, if possible. Otherwise there's not much Access can do other than drag all the data to the local machine over the wire and compare it on your little PC rather than the big beefy server. I'm making some assumptions here, but I've spent a _lot_ of time speeding things up by moving this kind of query from Access to the appropriate server(s).

Answer (score 1):

On the face of it I would say the problem is that access is trying to do this query locally and is pulling most of the table down the wire. This is where you often get the myth that access does this all of the time when in fact it only does it on certain edge events. Is there anyway you could narrow down the data you are comparing? Maybe the table is a list of product sales and you could do one product line at a time or something like that?

Comment: Yup, agreed. One nasty thing to try: if it's going to drag the tables down manually anyway, you might want to do that explicitly, that is separate your query into two steps, one that makes local copies of the tables (perhaps narrowing down the columns to the minimum necessary) and then one that compares the two locally. That's less likely to hang. But all else being equal, you're better off trying to do this on one of the servers if you can possibly manage it.